# É possível definir o charset em uma requisição ajax?

Tags: ajax

Estou com um problema com os caracteres. Eu basicamente abro arquivos txt(com acento) através do ajax, mas estou tendo problema com os acentos. Queria saber se há uma forma do ajax abrir o arquivo txt com acentos.

```html
<script charset="UTF-8" >
    function corpo(titulo, texto) {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = titulo;
            document.getElementById("corpo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", 'arquivos/'+texto, true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

É preciso salvar o arquivo de texto com o formato utf-8. Abrir o arquivo usando o bloco de notas, clicar em "salvar como..." e ao lado do botão "Salvar" alterar para utf-8